# Does the word "table" have anything to do with a table?

Tags: etymology, nouns

I am curious to know why a numerical chart can be called a *table*. What is the relation to the table at which people eat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That kind of table comes from the Latin *tabula* meaning "a board or plank" which was used for writing down columns of numbers. It was also where one ate one's dinner (OE called it *bord* and appropriated the Latin table for that purpose, although the Romans used the term *mensa* for the food table). Handy, eh? You can read about it on Etymonline. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=table&searchmode=none

Comment: And *bord* is from Dutch. How the languages became confused to form English!

Comment: Are you sure "bord" is from Dutch? I think it is part of the common inheritance of Dutch and English.

Comment: @Paul Lammertsma: I believe @Colin Fine's comment is addressed to you.

Comment: @Paul - I don't think it's that simple... you also have it in Swedish , Norwegian and Danish (e.g. Smörgåsbord, koldtbord)

Answer (score 3):

As reported from the NOAD, the origin of the word *table* is from Old English *tabule* (*flat slab, inscribed tablet*), which derives from the Latin *tabula* (*plank, tablet, list*); it has been reinforced in Middle English from the Old French *table*.

*Table* has then two different meanings that has been taken from the Latin word.

Comment: It's also behind "tablet", originally in the biblical sense (the stone tablets on which the Ten Commandments were inscribed).